# Using github.com GUI

Tags: github

I accidentally created 2 branches off of my master fork of a project.  I want to delete one of them but AFAICT the only time the GUI will offer a delete button for a *branch* is after a merge pull request is accepted.  Is there no way to just obliterate a branch, particularly one which is identical to another branch?  I am aware of the "Danger Zone" in settings where I believe an entire repository can be deleted but that is somewhat more than what is desired.  Thanks.

Comment: If you click 'branches' (next to 'commits') there should be a trashcan at the end of each branch line.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.